# Convert Integer to GUID by bytes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the c#

```
    public static Guid ToGuid(long value)
    {
        var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        var inputBuffer = new byte[16];

        for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            inputBuffer[i] = buffer[i];
        }

        return new Guid(inputBuffer);
    }
```

Is there anyway to replicate this functionality in TSQL?

Comment: You are aware that a GUID isn't just an arbitrary collection of bytes right?

Comment: A `long` is 8 bytes. A GUID is 16. What this method produces isn't even a valid GUID. Can you do this in T-SQL? Sure, if you take into account that [SQL Server uses a different way of ordering the bytes](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx). Should you do it in T-SQL? No, no more than in C#. Use a `BINARY(8)` type if you need to store 8 bytes.

Comment: Also, what is your source data here?, is it a `bigint`?

Comment: Yes I am aware this is a huge misuse, we tried to explain that to the client.

Comment: This isn't a misuse, it is completely wrong. It is like planting a potato and expecting to get an ipad when you harvest.

Comment: The byte swizzling involved make this a big pain in the ass, by the way. Compare `byte[] g = new byte[16]; Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x0102030405060708), 0, g, 0, 8); new Guid(g)` with `SELECT CAST(0x0102030405060708 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` to see what I mean. T-SQL does support bitwise operations, but it's still no fun. The question is whether you need code that has conceptually the same bone-headedly wrong effect (in which case `SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, CONVERT(BINARY(16), 123456))` will do) or whether you need code that produces the same bit-for-bit result as the C# code.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'DEADBEEF-C0DE-C0DE-' + STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(16), CONVERT(BINARY(8), CONVERT(BIGINT, 72623859790382856)), 2), 5, 0, '-'))`. There you go, one GUID that's so obviously invalid that it won't fool anyone, but still has 8 custom bytes in there. Extracting them is left as an exercise to the reader. The C# equivalent is `Guid.Parse("DEADBEEF-C0DE-C0DE-" + String.Format("{0:X16}", 72623859790382856).Insert(4, "-"))`. Disclaimer: global uniqueness definitely not guaranteed...

Comment: [Mark Whatney](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/the-martian/images/1/18/Mark_Watney.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150608134727) could do it @SeanLange

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code would be:

```
DECLARE @i INT=123456
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,CONVERT(BINARY(4),REVERSE(CONVERT(CHAR(4),CONVERT(BINARY(4),@i)))))
```

Here is another simpler option (but it does not produce the same results):

```
DECLARE @i INT=123456
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,CONVERT(BINARY(4),@i))
```

However, as other have warned in the comments, both these methods do not produce a valid GUID. As specified in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format, a valid GUID would need to have a version and a variant and there is no version 0, variant 0.